# Elasticsearch Min/Max aggregation returned the value_as_string in 'format'+'epochtimeinmillis'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-7

In Elasticsearch 7.16, for some date fields the Min/Max aggregation returned a value as 'format_specifiedin*_*the_aggregation'+'epochtimeinmillis', however for some other date fields it is returning the expected value for value_as_string.

The two fields : serviceDate and udf41

Mappings:

```
"serviceDate": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "epoch_millis || yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss || yyyy-MM-dd"
},
"udf41": {
  "type": "date",
  "format": "epoch_millis || yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss || yyyy-MM-dd"
}
```

Aggregations:

```
"aggregations": {
  "udf41_max": {
    "max": {
      "field": "udf41",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
  },
  "serviceDate": {
    "max": {
      "field": "serviceDate",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
"aggregations": {
  "serviceDate": {
    "value": 1.6927488E12,
    "value_as_string": "2023-08-23"
  },
  "udf41_max": {
    "value": 1.6828128E12,
    "value_as_string": "yyyy-MM-dd1682812800000"
  }
}
```

Both fields have the same mappings, and even when I attempted to send a different format in the aggregation, the same scenario replicated.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Could you provide the actual documents ? what is inside the _source. To help us reproduce

Comment: Here's the _source @Paulo
{
  "_index": "<index_name>",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "Content:Claims:cLs97RUS3jd7OXUiDkQGsw",
  "_score": 0.0,
  "_source": {
    "udf41": 1664323200000,
    "paidDate": 1662076800000,
    "serviceDate": 1662076800000
  }
}

Comment: @Paulo sorry that i could not provide you full hits; a new index has already been processed in the cluster, and the date field is not experiencing the aforementioned problem.
If I run across a datefield issue once more, I'll provide further details.